# Storage of data type char

Tags: c

Somewhat oddly, C treats character constants as type  int  rather than type  char. For example, on an ASCII system with a 32-bit  int  and an 8-bit  char, the code

```
char grade = 'B';
```

represents  `'B'`  as the numerical value 66 stored in a 32-bit unit, but  grade  winds up with 66 stored in an 8-bit unit. 
Please explain this lines.

Comment: This is how C works. A character constant has a type `int` by C standard.

Comment: Not necessarily 8 bit uint. Could be other width, also could be singed, all implementation defined.

Comment: @user3528438; The OP said "8-bit unit", not "8-bit uint", and explicitly stated the *assumption* that `int` is 32 bits, `char` is 8 bits, and the system uses ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

`grade` is of type `char`, and it's initialized with an expression of type `int`. That's perfectly ordinary and legal, and the `int` value is implicitly converted to type `char`. A value of any arithmetic type can be implicitly converted to any other arithmetic type.

Such implicit conversions are why, 99% of the time, the fact that character constants are of type `int` is not a problem; such constants are converted as appropriate depending on the context.

(Note that in C++ character constants are of type `char`. Remember that C and C++ are two different languages.)

Comment: @PSkocik: Thanks for the edit. I knew what I meant, it just didn't correspond to what my fingers typed for me.